# can a Ruby cloud instance handle the same amount of traffic a node instance would do?

Tags: ruby, node.js, content-management-system, scalability

We're going to work on revamping a cms based website for a tv channel that we expect to serve at least 10+ million unique user/month, about 400+ million requests/month and an average of 40 terabytes of bandwidth/month that's their CloudFlare stats from their old website and they expecting even more.

the team stack is mainly ruby/rails with react for the frontend, so we're planning to build the backend as rest API that serves a frontend react and another react app for the cms admin panel, we're arguing between Ruby and node and some says that node is faster and will be cheaper in terms of resources consumption, will Ruby be efficient vs node?, can a Ruby cloud instance handle the same amount of traffic a node instance would do? any advice on is it worth the shift to node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally CMS applications heavily use caching, and I mean really heavily, like 99.999% of your requests must be cached and served by Apache/Nginx or a dedicated cache server. And thus the performance of your web framework doesn't matter too much.

Without caching that level of load on moderate hardware can create quite a lot of trouble both for Node and for Rails. For Rails that kind of load (400M/mo = 150 rps on average + 10–100x spikes) will require quite a few decent dedicated servers. Node should be about 2–5 times faster, depending on how SQL-heavy your requests are.

Comment: so generally speaking Ruby will require at least double the number of servers or cloud instances a node would need, in case they both were tuned right?

Comment: Definitely, probably it will be more than double.

Answer (score 0):

The reason node can handle such high throughput is due to it's highly parallelised nature and the fact that the JS JIT is incredibly optimized and can do certain things for performance boosts that ruby can't plus, want more performance? Just allow it to run with more threads.
You can do the same using a webserver like Puma and configure it to run with more threads but ultimately it's still ruby based.

What you could do is to use more smaller frameworks such as using sinatra for the front end and grape for the backend, smaller means lighter thus less load. 
Also maybe apache for static asset distribution or offload entirely to a static asset server. On top of that If you're able to you can code performance critical components in a lower level language such as C, C++, Rust, etc.

Lastly you can try for specific ruby optimizations, I don't know off the top of my head but I'm sure they exist though how much you'll get from them I can't say.

Ruby Itself won't really be reasonably fast by itself until at least ruby 3.0 and I'm not sure when that is coming out.